# Get sound from a URL with Java

Tags: java, url, audio, mp3, javasound

I'm learning english and I'd like to develop a software to help me with the pronunciation.

There is a site called HowJSay, if you enter here: http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=car
immediatly you'll hear the pronunciation of the word car . I'd like to develop a software in JAVA that could play this sound without necessity of enter in the site =]

I tried this, but doesn't work =/

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=car");
    url.openConnection();
    AudioStream as = new AudioStream(url.openStream());
    AudioPlayer.player.start(as);
    AudioPlayer.player.stop(as);
}
```

Any Ideas? Please.

Comment: How it does not work? Exception or nothing happens? The constructor you use does not seem right.

Comment: How did you expect that url returns a sound file ?

Comment: Actually, real URL is: http://www.howjsay.com/mp3/car.mp3

Comment: `AudioStream`, `AudioPlayer`?  Not in J2SE 7 docs.  Is this for Android?

Comment: @AndrewThompson, it is sun.audio . Is this outdated/deprecated?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov  The compiler itself warns us not to use them.  Since 1.3 we have Java Sound (see my answer & links).

Answer (score 4):

Here you go

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class HowJSay
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AudioInputStream din = null;
    try {
        AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new URL("http://www.howjsay.com/mp3/"+ args[0] +".mp3"));
        AudioFormat baseFormat = in.getFormat();
        AudioFormat decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(
                AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                baseFormat.getSampleRate(), 16, baseFormat.getChannels(),
                baseFormat.getChannels() * 2, baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                false);
        din = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, in);
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, decodedFormat);
        SourceDataLine line = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        if(line != null) {
            line.open(decodedFormat);
            byte[] data = new byte[4096];
            // Start
            line.start();

            int nBytesRead;
            while ((nBytesRead = din.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                line.write(data, 0, nBytesRead);
            }
            // Stop
            line.drain();
            line.stop();
            line.close();
            din.close();
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if(din != null) {
            try { din.close(); } catch(IOException e) { }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I got a error in this code =/  javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input URL
 at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at HowJSay.main(HowJSay.java:10)

Comment: @javando do you run this program with argument? first argument has to be word

Comment: I put the argument. and I got the exception that I put above. It's in the line 10, first line inside the try.

Comment: I'm thinking in get another way. First download the mp3 file (It's good to make some cache) and after, play the mp3 file. I'm researching about how to play a mp3 in java and it's been  dificult. If someone knows how to do that, It would be helpful =]

Comment: @javando, maybe you are behind proxy.

Comment: @Nikolay Kuznetsov I'm not behind a proxy =/  I stoped the firewall too =/

Comment: @javando use my code to play from file. `getAudioInputStream` can take File as the parameter. If this does not work then problem is related to your system configuration. If it works then problem is related to connection between you and howjsay. That's just idea.

Comment: I'm downloading the new Java7 that have the javafx api, and i'll try download the mp3 and play like explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045384/playing-mp3-and-wav-in-java

Comment: @javando i'm running this code on Java 7 if that matters. Let me now how it turns out for you

Comment: @Marek I'm not understanding =/ with file I got javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input file
 at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1187)
 at HowJSay.main(HowJSay.java:15)                                    I think that there is something wrong with my java installation

Comment: @javando can't tell much from that little information. Try to use latest version of JDK and hopefully you will not have that problems.

Comment: I updated my java and keep without work =/ I'll try with the API of javafx.

Comment: I got it =] Thank you for all. I followed this article: introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/faq/mp3/MP3.java.html I'll download the mp3 and play it =]

Answer (score 2):

[Java Sound](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) can play short clips easily, but supports a limited number of formats out of the box.  The formats it supports by default are given by [`AudioSystem.getAudioFileTypes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioFileTypes%28%29) & that list will not include MP3.

The solution to the lack of support for MP3 is to add a decoder to the run-time class-path of the app.  Since Java Sound works on a Service Provider Interface, it only needs to be on the class-path to be useful.  An MP3 decoder can be found in [`mp3plugin.jar`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5B9wDXIGw9lRmpSbEUtenljd1k/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-miuzcGB8fsXn2EQh3sVolA).

As to the code for playing the MP3, the short source on the info. page should suffice so long as the clips are short.  Viz.

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class LoopSound {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL(
            "http://pscode.org/media/leftright.wav");
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        // getAudioInputStream() also accepts a File or InputStream
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.
            getAudioInputStream( url );
        clip.open(ais);
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // A GUI element to prevent the Clip's daemon Thread
                // from terminating at the end of the main()
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Close to exit!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care much about the site then you try to use Google Translate API

```
try{
        String word="car";
        word=java.net.URLEncoder.encode(word, "UTF-8");
        URL url = new URL("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&tl=ja&q="+word);
        HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76");
        InputStream audioSrc = urlConn.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream read = new DataInputStream(audioSrc);
        AudioStream as = new AudioStream(read);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(as);
        AudioPlayer.player.stop(as);
}
```

With help from here:
[Java: download Text to Speech from Google Translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339421/java-download-text-to-speech-from-google-translate)

If for every `word` the site guarantees to have mp3 file with link `howjsay.com/mp3/word.mp3` then you just need to change URL to

`URL url = new URL("howjsay.com/mp3/" + word + ".mp3");`

Answer (score 0):

If you're having issues with the code provided by Marek, make sure you're meeting this criteria:

1. Use a supported audio format, such as 16 bit .wav
2. Make sure that the URL you're using is actually playing audio automatically.

It isn't sufficient to simply reference the download page for an audio file. It has to be streaming the audio. YouTube URLs won't work, as they're videos. Audacity is a good approach to converting your audio file to a compatible 16 bit .wav file, and if you have your own domain / website, you can provide a direct link to the file from there.