# Home directory not accessible: Permission denied java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching interface SourceDataLine

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, java-8, javasound

I am trying to play an online [WAV audio file](http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-01a.wav) from [Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789063/get-sound-from-a-url-with-java/13789526#13789526).

My OS: Ubuntu 14.04. Java version: 8.

On my machine, it does play the file when I run the code from a stand alone java application.

But when I call this code from code that runs in Tomcat, I am getting the following exception:

```
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching interface SourceDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian is supported.
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getLine(AudioSystem.java:479)
```

Tomcat runs on my machine, as a service.

Why doesn't it work from Tomcat?

Comment: *"On my machine, it does play the file when I run the code from a stand alone java application.

But when I call this code from code that runs in Tomcat,.."* Wait ..what? Is that a server? If someone could connect from outside your network to the server, where would you expect the sound to be heard? The server machine or the client machine?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I expect the audio file to be played on the server machine. Just like sending text to the standard output. But when I test it, the server machine is my local machine.

Comment: Servers often run 'headless' which means they have no monitors and no speakers.. Check if Tomcat is running in headless mode.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I have changed Tomcat's settings to `JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=false ...` but still the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a `sudo chown -R 'username':'username' /home/'username'` and then using `pavucontrol` to unmute the output.
More information can be found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=6208727)

Comment: Why do you think it's a good idea to do so? I have many areas in my home that are owned by root.